# Checking differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this DE
$$
\sin x·y'+4y·\cos x= y^{1/2}
$$
which is a Bernoulli equation

Transforming the above into a first order linear DE I found as a solution the following:
$$
y = \left(\frac{-30\cos x + 20(\cos x)^3 -6(\cos x)^5 + c}{20·(\sin x)^6}\right)^2 ,
$$
where $c$ a constant of $R$

but everywhere i get as a solution the following
$$
y = \frac{(\cos x-c)^2}{4\sin x^4}
$$
which by the way looks much better.

Is my solution correct, just in a different form?

Thanks

Comment: You can always check your solution to the differential equation by taking the derivative...

Comment: Its a complicated expression, is there an easier way? Also is there a point to characterize the above DE as homogenous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $y=u^2$, then either $u=0$ or the equation reduces to
$$
\sin x·u'+2\cos x·u=\frac12
$$
The integrating factor for this equation is $\sin x$, so that
$$
\sin^2x·u=C-\frac12\cos x
$$
Thus the reference solution easily follows. You would have to give some of your steps if you want to discuss where the solution went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So my solution is for sure wrong?

Comment: Also can you explain how did you think of setting y=u^2? I followed the steps for solving the bernulli equation by multiplying all the terms with y^(-1/2) and then setting u = y^(1/2). It is the same thing but yours is so much easier.

Comment: First, is it still your solution? It was not completely clear how the factors were to be grouped. And yes, at least the terms associated with the constant seem to be incompatible. One could probably reduce other terms somewhat using $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$. You would need to present more steps after the initial ones to to try to find out if you zigged where you should have zagged,...

Comment: Yes that's my solution. Do we generally prefer when y has a rational power y^(1/n) to set y = u^n instead of u = y^(1/n)?

Comment: It is equivalent, and for my taste, powers are easier than roots. But that only works that well if one way or the other one has integer powers. With other powers following strictly the standard method should avoid more errors.